# Semi-continuity for extended value function

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

Given a topological vector space $(X,\tau)$ a function $f:(X,\tau)\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ is said to be lower-semicontinuous at $x_0\in X$ if

$$
f(x_0)\le\liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x):=\sup_{V\in\mathscr{V}(x_0)}\inf_{x\in V}f(x),
$$
where $\mathscr{V}(x_0)$ stands for the system of neighborhoods of $x_0$.

Similarly, the upper-semicontinuity at $x_0$ is defined with "$\ge\limsup$" instead of "$\le\liminf$".

My question are: If a function is identically equal to $+\infty$ is it lower and upper semicontinuous everywhere?

Is such a function continuous everywhere? (Continuity requires $f(x_0)\in\mathbb{R}$)

My questions are more about formalism and asks about a discussion on basic definitions. As stated somewhere in a book,  a function is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if it is both upper and lower semi-continuous there.

Comment: In other words, your definition of continuity as a map $X\to\bar{\mathbb{R}}\cong[-1,1]$ is different from continuity as a map $X\to\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f \equiv +\infty$, and $x_0 \in X$ then whatever $V \in \mathscr{V}(x_0)$ is, $\displaystyle \inf_{x \in V} f(x)=+\infty$ and so $f$ is trivially lsc at $x_0$. That $f$ is also usc is checked the same way.

BTW it's perfectly fine to talk about continuity at $x_0$ if $f(x_) = +\infty$. Maybe your text book thinks differently but $\overline{\Bbb R}$ has an (even metrisable) order topology, so continuity can be discussed...